# Trigger a function whenever ng-repeat filtered length changes

Tags: angularjs

I need to create a graphical report based on length(quantity(result.lenght)) of records, so i need trigger a function whenever the length changes

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="myleads in (filterResult = (myoldrec | lter:search))">
    {{myleads.value0}} - {{myleads.value1}} -- {{$index}}
</div>
<input type='text' ng-value='filterResult.length' ng-model='myfilterlength'>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.$watch('myfilterlength',function(){
    alert();
})
```

The above `$watch` function is not triggering.

Answer (score 1):

try this ( you can remove ng-value ):

```
$scope.$watch('filterResult',function(newV){
   $scope.myfilterlength = newV.length;
})
```

Comment: Hi vanoj, i try to use the code but its triggering the function multiple times. Guess, it triggering each time 'filterResult' getting data from the loop.

Comment: each time something change in the filterResult your input value will be updated

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to use `ng-change`:

```
<input type='text' ng-value='filterResult.length' ng-model='myfilterlength' ng-change="changed()>
```

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apimenov93/voqgp860/1/)